# FlowType : why function types have named parameters ? What is their purpose?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Let's consider [this](https://flowtype.org/try/#0FDDGHsDsGcBcAICGATZ8C88AUB3AForACrgCCqAXJAK4C2ARgKYBOAlPBdisiVXU2wwA+GgxbCA3sHjxmjWNWaQuqEkTwBLaK3RDuazdADU+QiXLJgAXxAQYCbgGYMSVFketbUOLMbQXTlgALJ7AQA) code:

```
const add = (whatToAdd:number) : (addTo:number) =>number =>{
  return (addToThis)=>addToThis+whatToAdd
}

const add3 = add(3)

const res = add3(4)
```

Why can I not write `number => number` instead of `(addTo:number) =>number` ?

What purpose can the name `addTo` have at all ?

Comment: I access it using `addToThis` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, in Flow 0.34:

```
const add = (whatToAdd:number) : (number => number) =>{
  return (addToThis)=>addToThis+whatToAdd
}
```